# Does "for despite" just mean despite?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, prepositions, synonyms

***For despite*** what the great Sensei Tsuji's tone may lead us to believe, Japanese cuisine like Japanese culture generally—has always been ready to assimilate foreign ideas that have demonstrated their usefulness.

I think "for despite" probably just means "despite".However is there subtle difference between them or it’s just a wordy way to say the exactly same thing?

Comment: 'For' here may arguably (some don't like to start a fragment with 'because') be replaced by 'because'. You need to show the previous sentence for this to make sense. Then drop the concessive / reasoning  'despite what the great Sensei Tsuji's tone may lead us to believe' and substitute 'because' for 'for', to see that this makes sense.

Comment: For isn't closely bound with despite here. I would have put a comma after for because "despite...to believe" is an independent clause.

Comment: Yeah, "for" is being used as a conjunction, meaning "because".